# DXA controller is not able to get post request parameter

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I am trying to submit a login form with the post request but I am not getting all the request parameters (like username, and password) in the controller.

JavaScript code:

```
loadurl = doamainName + "/ajax-call-handler";
$.ajax({
    url: loadurl,
    method: "POST",
    data: dataField
}).done(function (data) {
}
```

Controller code:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/{languageName}/{pageName}")
    public String handleGetPage(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariables, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String ajaxPageName = request.getParameter("ajaxPageName");
        if (ajaxPageName == null || ajaxPageName.length() == 0) ajaxPageName = "None";
}
```

Comment: Wow, sort your code formatting out! Is this Java Dxa?

Comment: Yes. Based on DXA Java 1.0

Comment: Seems like a general Spring MVC question to me... Anyways, I don't see any evidence in your code samples that request parameters are sent by the client, nor that any are expected by the server (?)